# Usage of \seq_map_inline:Nn and/or \tl_clear:N

Tags: expl3

I trust the code below is commented sufficiently well to obviate further explanations. The macro defined in the MWE does not produce the expected result. My reading of `\seq_map_inline:Nn \params_seq` in the interface3 document is that ##1 presents tokens stored in `\params_seq` one at a time, and that `\tl_clear:N \output_tl` will clear the tokenlist. The result suggests I misread either one or the other, possibly both.

I will be grateful for any help received.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
%-----------------------------
%RN 24 August 2015
%   BACKGROUND:
% The purpose of the macro is to provide the template for macros 
% that accept a parameter input stream of arbitrary length 
% (separator optionally definable), and partition it into chunks 
% of optionally defineable length for further processing.   
%   ISSUE:
% I expect the result to be:
%   1 2 3 4 5
%   6 7 8 9 10
%   11 12 13 14 15
%   16 17
% and not:       
%   1 2 3 4 5
%   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
%   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
%   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17        
%-----------------------------
\usepackage{xparse}
%=======================================
\ExplSyntaxOn
%-----------------------------
\tl_new:N \output_tl 
\seq_new:N \params_seq 
\int_new:N \index_i
%-----------------------------
\NewDocumentCommand\myPartitionerTemplate{O{,} m O{3}}{\myPartitioner_build:nn {#1}{#2}{#3}}
\cs_new:Npn \myPartitioner_build:nn #1 #2 #3
  { %begin control sequence
    \tl_clear:N \output_tl 
    \seq_clear:N \params_seq 
    \int_set:Nn \index_i { 0 }
  %load parameter #2 into the _seq array:
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \params_seq { #1 } { #2 }  
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \params_seq  
        {   %begin processing \params_seq inline
            % keep a count of how many parameters have been read:
            \int_incr:N \index_i    
            \tl_put_right:Nn \output_tl {\ ##1 }    
            %   once a partition is full, i.e. paramcount mod   param#3 = 0,
            % "use" it, then clear \output_tl: 
            \if_int_compare:w  \int_mod:nn {\index_i} {#3} = 0
                {
                \tl_use:N \output_tl \\ 
                \tl_clear:N \output_tl
                }       
            \fi:
        }   %end inline processing
        %   "use" final partially full partition, else it's 
        % been "used" already
        \if_int_compare:w  \int_mod:nn {\index_i} {#3} > 0
            \tl_use:N \output_tl \\
        \fi:
  } %end control sequence
\ExplSyntaxOff
%=======================================
\begin{document}
\verb+\myPartitionerTemplate{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}[5]+\\
\myPartitionerTemplate{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Manuel Name three. If you have nothing else to contribute, Manuel, I suggest your remain silent.

Comment: @Manuel My apologies for being abrasive. Every time I work with `Latex3` I get over-excited, not to say nervous, and this often translates to jumpy and erratic behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is

```
\if_int_compare:w  \int_mod:nn {\index_i} {#3} = 0
  {
    \tl_use:N \output_tl \\ 
    \tl_clear:N \output_tl
  }
\fi:
```

Here you are using the lowest-level numerical conditional, `\if_int_compare:w` (the TeX `\ifnum` primitive), which does *not* use brace groups for its argument. Thus the `{ ... }` pair here cause a group to applied to the `\tl_clear:N` and you therefore do not get the expected reset behaviour.

You could fix by removing the stray group, but I'd favour `\int_comapre:nNnTF` (or `\int_compare:nTF`) here, which *does* use a brace group and which does not need you to watch the fact you've not safely terminated your conditionals. Tidying up the code to use higher-level interfaces where available, correctly-named variables, *etc.*, leads to

```
\documentclass{article}
%-----------------------------
%RN 24 August 2015
%   BACKGROUND:
% The purpose of the macro is to provide the template for macros 
% that accept a parameter input stream of arbitrary length 
% (separator optionally definable), and partition it into chunks 
% of optionally definable length for further processing.   
%   ISSUE:
% I expect the result to be:
%   1 2 3 4 5
%   6 7 8 9 10
%   11 12 13 14 15
%   16 17

%-----------------------------
\usepackage{xparse}
%=======================================
\ExplSyntaxOn
%-----------------------------
\tl_new:N \l__myPartitioner_output_tl 
\seq_new:N \l__myPartitioner_params_seq 
\int_new:N \l__myPartitioner_index_int
%-----------------------------
\NewDocumentCommand\myPartitionerTemplate{O{,} m O{3}}
  {\myPartitioner_build:nnn {#1}{#2}{#3}}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \myPartitioner_build:nnn #1 #2 #3
  { %begin control sequence
    \tl_clear:N \l__myPartitioner_output_tl 
    \seq_clear:N \l__myPartitioner_params_seq 
    \int_zero:N \l__myPartitioner_index_int
  %load parameter #2 into the _seq array:
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__myPartitioner_params_seq {#1} {#2}  
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__myPartitioner_params_seq  
      { %begin processing \l__myPartitioner_params_seq inline
        % keep a count of how many parameters have been read:
        \int_incr:N \l__myPartitioner_index_int    
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__myPartitioner_output_tl
           { \c_space_tl ##1 }    
        %   once a partition is full, i.e. paramcount mod   param#3 = 0,
        % "use" it, then clear \l__myPartitioner_output_tl: 
        \int_compare:nNnT
          { \int_mod:nn { \l__myPartitioner_index_int } {#3} } = \c_zero
          {
            \tl_use:N \l__myPartitioner_output_tl \\ 
            \tl_clear:N \l__myPartitioner_output_tl      
          }
      }   % end inline processing
      % "use" final partially full partition, else it's 
      % been "used" already
    \int_compare:nNnT
       { \int_mod:nn {\l__myPartitioner_index_int } {#3} } > \c_zero
       { \tl_use:N \l__myPartitioner_output_tl }
  } %end control sequence
\ExplSyntaxOff
%=======================================
\begin{document}
\verb+\myPartitionerTemplate{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}[5]+\\
\myPartitionerTemplate{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now that you pointed me in the right direction it is clear I should have had a more careful look at the possibilities offered to compare integers. I did have an uneasy feeling about that `:w` at the end of `\if_int_compare:w`, had quick read in the manual, didn't grasp the half of it, and went and used it anyway. Your modified code works, I mark it down as the answer. I have taken your recommendations on board and feel I learnt something from the experience. Thanks.

Comment: There's one thing missing, `:nn #1 #2 #3` should be `:nnn #1 #2 #3`.

Comment: @Joseph I notice you replaced my naïve use of `0` with `\c_zero` and `\ ` with `\c_space` and wonder if this touches on some fundamental misunderstanding in my head on how to use constants in `latex3`. Can you point me in the right direction on this point?

Comment: @Manuel Well spotted: fixed

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth Pre-defined constants have a (slight) performance gain over literal numbers, so using `\c_zero` is very slightly faster than using `0`. They are also 'self-terminating', important if you use `\if_int_compare:w` (less so for `\int_compare:nNnTF`, which includes the termination internally). On the space, `\c_space_tl` _expands_ to a space, so if we did for example an `x`-type expansion you'd end up with a literal space, whereas `\ ` is a non-expandable primitive (outside special contexts). As such, the former is probably what you wanted.